# Data files for some packages could not be downloaded - font instalation

Tags: software-installation, fonts, ubuntu-restricted-extras

After updating to Ubuntu 14.04, I installed Ubuntu restricted extras and then the Software Center crashed during the installation so I had to terminate the window. I removed and re-installed it and found that the MS fonts are not installed in my OS. Once in a while I'd get the bellow message (I've tried to re-install the MS true type core font package a few times but I still cannot see the fonts):

```
Data files for some packages could not be downloaded
The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.
ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

This is a permanent failure that leaves these packages unusable on your system.  You may need to fix your Internet connection, then remove and reinstall the packages to fix this problem.

Comment: does the progress continuously appearing beside histroy tab in software center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close `Software Center`

Type this in terminal

`sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

Identify the PID of the process causing lock then stop that process

`sudo kill -TERM <PID>`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Answer (score 4):

Using the old command:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

for installing Times New Roman font in Ubuntu 14.04.

If you're already tried using ttf-mscorefonts-installer, please reinstall the font using:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install msttcorefonts
```

It works for me.