# Windows-like fonts in Ubuntu

Tags: fonts, desktop-environments

I'm pretty familiar with Ubuntu and Linux in general. I use Ubuntu at work for software development. What always bothers me about Ubuntu is the fonts - I really like the crisp fonts used all over Windows (the program bar, headers, etc.) and compared to them, the Ubuntu fonts seem bulky and weird.

In the past, I had several Ubuntu installations on multiple devices, but I could never seem to configure the fonts to my satisfaction. Even the results I *did* get cost me hours and hours of reading online and configuring fonts in obscure menus and files. I know it probably sounds silly, but this is currently the main reason I don't install Ubuntu on my laptop right now.

Is there a package, script or window manager for Ubuntu that set up fonts in a way that is similar to Windows, without too much hassle of a configuration?

Comment: Relevant. http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make fonts look like they do in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897/how-can-i-make-fonts-look-like-they-do-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu also uses the `ttf` format. Simply download any font and double click to install it.

---

Windows fonts are avaliable on Ubuntu, including Arial and Times New Roman.

> Using the old command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
> ```
>
> for installing Times New Roman font etc.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/472734/186134)

---

To configure them - you want Unity Tweak Tool. Simply install it:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

And configure them in there.

Comment: This forces me to fiddle with the different fonts for the different sections, which from experience - will almost never be satisfactory. I'm looking for a no-hassle-one-click-and-your-ubuntu-looks-like-windows-fontwise solution :)

Comment: @AmirRachum That's not gonna happen, Ubuntu isn't trying to look like windows...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this article on WEB UPD8: [Better Font Rendering In Linux With Infinality](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html)

> **[Infinality](http://www.infinality.net/blog/)** is a set of Freetype patches that try to provide an improved font rendering for Linux and also, to allow easy
>   customization so the users can adjust the settings to their taste.
>   Using it, you can easily set the font style to emulate OSX, OSX2,
>   **Windows 98, WIndows XP or Windows 7** or you can use the "Linux" or "Infinality" (default) styles.
>
> This is just an example (left the "Linux" style, right the default
>   Ubuntu config).
>
> [image]
>
> Freetype with the Infinality patches can be installed in Ubuntu by
>   using a PPA. To add the PPA and install the required packages in
>   Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, 14.10 or 15.04 use the following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality
> ```
>
> Once installed, log out and log back in.
>
> Once you install Infinality, it's time to configure it. To set the
>   style you want to use, run the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo bash /etc/fonts/infinality/infctl.sh setstyle
> ```
>
> And select the style you want to use. Available options are: debug,
>   infinality, linux, osx, osx2, win7, win98 and winxp (I recommend using
>   the "linux" style, obviously, but you can try any style, then remember
>   to log out and log back in - you can easily select a different style
>   later on by using the same command). To use the Windows or OSX style
>   you'll also need to use the Windows or OSX fonts.
>
> Optional: next, open /etc/profile.d/infinality-settings.sh with a text
>   editor as root - I'll use Gedit below:
>
> ```
> sudo -H gedit /etc/profile.d/infinality-settings.sh
> ```
>
> And in this file, search for USE_STYLE (it should be
>   USE_STYLE="DEFAULT" by default) and change it to one of the following
>   styles (I recommend using "UBUNTU" here but you should also try the
>   default to see which one you like better):
>
> - DEFAULT - A compromise that should please most people;
> - OSX - Simulate OSX rendering;
> - IPAD - Simulate iPad rendering;
> - UBUNTU - Simulate Ubuntu rendering;
> - LINUX - Generic "Linux" style - no snapping or certain other tweaks;
> - WINDOWS - Simulate Windows rendering;
> - WINDOWS7 - Simulate Windows rendering with normal glyphs;
> - WINDOWS7LIGHT- Simulate Windows 7 rendering with lighter glyphs;
> - WINDOWS - Simulate Windows rendering;
> - VANILLA - Just subpixel hinting;
> - CUSTOM - Your own choice;
> - Infinality styles:
>
>   - CLASSIC - Infinality rendering circa 2010. No snapping;
>   - NUDGE - CLASSIC with lightly stem snapping and tweaks;
>   - PUSH - CLASSIC with medium stem snapping and tweaks;
>   - SHOVE - Full stem snapping and tweaks without sharpening;
>   - SHARPENED - Full stem snapping, tweaks, and Windows-style sharpening;
>   - INFINALITY - Settings used by the Infinality developer;
>   - DISABLED - Act as though running without the extra infinality enhancements (just subpixel hinting).

Answer (score 0):

You can find most fonts in web. Here site that I downloaded Consolas font : https://freefontsdownload.net/free-consolas-font-33098.htm. Simply go and research for names of fonts that Microsoft Windows using. You probably can find them somewhere in system folders.